# IllegalStateException occured when deployed war in tomcat with spring boot 2.0.1

Tags: spring-boot

I packaged a war with gradle + boot 2.0.1, gradle script as below

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.0.1.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
    id 'war'
}

apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'

dependencyManagement {
    imports {
        mavenBom org.springframework.boot.gradle.plugin.SpringBootPlugin.BOM_COORDINATES
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
bootWar{
    mainClassName = 'api.abroad.Application'
}

configurations {
    providedRuntime
}
dependencies {
    compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    providedRuntime 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat'
}
```

The Application class with main function as below

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

and I also wirted a class extends SpringBootServletInitializer to override configure function, although it was not required in docs.

```
public class ServletInitializer extends SpringBootServletInitializer{

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(Application.class);
    }

}
```

I installed tomcat 8.5.29 in my windows, and deployed the war. An exception occured as below

```
2018-04-09 14:40:19.978  INFO 11720 --- [ost-startStop-1] com.tbiedu.abroad.ServletInitializer     : Started ServletInitializer in 4.113 seconds (JVM running for 10.228)
2018-04-09 14:40:19.989  INFO 11720 --- [ost-startStop-1] c.t.abroad.controller.DemoController     : Root context already created (using as parent).
09-Apr-2018 14:40:19.992 严重 [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal ContainerBase.addChild: start:
 org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/abroad-service-api]]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:167)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:754)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:730)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:734)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:986)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1857)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No SpringApplication sources have been defined. Either override the configure method or add an @Configuration annotation
        at org.springframework.util.Assert.state(Assert.java:73)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.createRootApplicationContext(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:127)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.onStartup(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:87)
        at org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(SpringServletContainerInitializer.java:172)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5204)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        ... 10 more
```

Did i missed something...

Comment: I am not sure what "docs" you're referring to but the section on `war` file has [an explicit section about it](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-create-a-deployable-war-file). It looks like you're reusing what start.spring.io does when you request the generation of a war project. That war project works fine for me so perhaps you can share your project somewhere?

Comment: Thank you metioned "reusing", so I recheck my code and found another "extends SpringBootServletInitializer" on a controller class. It's working fine after i removed the repeated one.

Answer (score 4):

you need to place @Configuration above this class

```
@Configuration//--> this line u need to place 
public class ServletInitializer extends SpringBootServletInitializer{
@Override
protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
    return application.sources(Application.class);
}
}
```